# Magento require a user to accept t&c's before they can access the site

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I've been asked to add a lightbox popup to a Magento site. It should appear the first time a user looks at the site so they have to check it before they can view the site or make a purchase.

If this isn't possible a JS popup or at the least just have the lightbox popup that needs to be clicked to dismiss it (but still allowing site access).

I've googled and looked on here, but everything seems to be related to the t&cs on the checkout page which isn't appropriate.

I'd appreciate any guidance or suggestions how to go about this.

Comment: I've not coded anything at the moment, I'm new to Magento and not really sure where to begin. I would be happy to save that the user had ticked the 'agree' box in a session or cookie and then check against this to determine whether they are returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cookies—perhaps [this library may help](http://code.google.com/p/cookies/)—save confirmation of T&C approval, and check on page load to detect whether user has confirmed.

Use some form of [lightbox](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&q=lightbox&oq=lightbox) to display your message and approval mechanism.

Any more exact detail would make anyone expect payment! :)

Comment: Thanks that should cover it (and avoid paying :O )

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps consider the AITOC Splash Page extension.  It provides exactly the capability you're describing and seems to work well. I haven't used it on a CE site, only on a Magento Pro 1.11.1.0 site. Their extension though is available for CE and EE as well.